# Low budget 70/80/90s film where men go through a factory and come out women

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have had flashbacks to a film I once saw on TV as a young lad. It stuck with me, but I’ve never been able to find it again.

It would have been on UK TV late night possibly channel 3 or 4 around late 90s. It felt older than that so may be 70s/80s. It was American, set in what would have been modern (dystopian) times. I recall a factory and someone managing to break in (very Soylent green style.) Inside, people (possibly just men) are on a conveyor belt, moving along. As they do, a small guillotine chops their male organ off and hey presto, they come out the other end as women.

Comment: There's a scene a bit like what you describe in The Ice Pirates.  See https://twincitiesgeek.com/2017/04/throwback-thursday-its-a-cool-cool-world-for-the-ice-pirates/

Comment: @DoscoJones Just watched that clip myself. It's unclear if OP means that the victims are literally transformed into women or if they're simply devoid of their "manhood", so this is a partial match for me

Comment: Agreed, it's a partial match.  Still, memories get weird as decades pass.  Found a clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KcTCRSZBUU

Comment: @DoscoJones is this a clip I am going to regret watching?

Comment: @lessthanideal nah, it's a comedy

Answer (score 9):

There's a scene a bit like what you describe in the 1984 sci-fi comedy [The Ice Pirates](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087451/).

[image]

The scene I remember has your dystopian factory setting complete with conveyor belt and chopper:

The men are turned into androgynous slaves:
[image]

This is not a complete match to your description, but memories do get hazy after 30+ years.